# How to use spaces in Template Literals?

Tags: javascript, html, template-literals

I have a `<li>` element showing dynamic content using *Template Literals* (template strings).

```
<li className='floatLeft'><span><b>Galley Details</b></span> <br/>{`${galleyCartsDet[0].quantity} Full Cart ${galleyCartsDet[1].quantity} Half Cart${galleyCartsDet[2].quantity} SMU${galleyCartsDet[3].quantity} Stowage`}</li>
```

How can I use spaces in the given template string?

```
`${galleyCartsDet[0].quantity} Full Cart ${galleyCartsDet[1].quantity} Half Cart${galleyCartsDet[2].quantity} SMU${galleyCartsDet[3].quantity} Stowage`
```

Comment: *"get a space after `${}` [...] space before the beginning of `${}`"* - Sorry, _where_ do you want the space? Your question is a bit unclear... Also, did you try an `&nbsp;`? That outputs a space too.

Comment: I need the space in the beginning of ${} . I am searching for &nbsp; usage inside `` literal

Comment: Needs more details such as where are you getting the variable from, and whether you are using any framework for this, and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spaces in a *template string* in this way:

```
`\u00A0\u00A0${option.value}\u00A0\u00A0`
```

`\u00A0` = non-breaking space
`\u0020` = normal space